# PHP get value under mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to get a value that is associated (through mysql data-base row) to a unique Id through an option form:

```
<form>
<td>
<select name='rolo'>
   <option value='$id'>$item</option>
</td>
<td>
   $value
</td>
</select>
</form>
```

So, when I choose an option, I get the correspondent $value associated with it in the next .

What I have tried so far:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM rolostock WHERE id='$id' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['value'];
}
```

I am not a php expertise, and I thought this would do it? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

What i'm trying is to (html form) SELECT > OPTION $id > (php) get $value of $id in the next (html) TD . :\

Comment: Some of your html is alil strange, what exactly is the error that you are getting?

Comment: sorry if not being very explicit :\ 
the error im getting is
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: try to see what error is.`echo mysql_error();` put after your query

Comment: Its not geting the value of id thats why query is not executed

Comment: That you all, ye the id was the problem! Beh so close and so far :\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `rolostock` WHERE id = '$id';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) exit("The query did not succeded");
else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['value'];
    }
}
```

If running this prints `The query did not succeded` then you have an error in your query. Try running it via PhpMyAdmin.

Also use:

```
<option value='<?php echo $id;?>'><?=php echo $item;?></option>
```

instead of:

```
<option value='$id'>$item</option>
```